# view table IF CASE condition not work properly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

View Table: don't work properly.
I have two tables

1. `Deposits`
2. `withdraws`

If:

```
Account no  = 101
balance = 100 $
Account no  = 102 
balance = 50 $
```

When i `withdraw` some `money` Like this account `A/C 101` Withdraw Amount `10$`
Now result : is minus all account balance

Current balance:

```
Account no  = 101
balance = 90 $ -10 $ 
Account no  = 102 
balance = 40 $ -10 $ // But 50
```

every account minus Deposit balance

```
CREATE VIEW main_balance_new as select account_no as account_no,
 SUM(deposit_amount)-(select 
  CASE 
    WHEN withdraw_amount IS NULL THEN 0
   ELSE SUM(withdraw_amount)
  END
  from withdraws) as balance from deposits group by account_no
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please share the definition of the 2 tables? And are you sure the numbers you save in `withdraws` are `> 0` ?

Comment: It can be `0` or any integer number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to aggregate the deposit and withdrawal tables separately:

```
CREATE VIEW d_view AS
SELECT account_no, SUM(deposit_amount) AS deposit_sum
FROM deposits
GROUP BY account_no

CREATE VIEW w_view AS
SELECT account_no, SUM(withdraw_amount) AS withdraw_sum
FROM withdraws
GROUP BY account_no

CREATE VIEW main_balance_new AS
SELECT
    d.account_no,
    d.deposit_sum - COALESCE(w.withdraw_sum, 0) AS balance
FROM d_view d
LEFT JOIN w_view w
    ON d.account_no = w.account_no;
```

This answer leaves open the possibility that a given account only appears in the deposit, but not the withdrawal, table.

**Edit:**

If you need a view, then use separate views to get around the subquery problem.

Comment: #1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: Um...you need subqueries here.  No way out AFAIK.

Comment: You can convert left join to view table

Comment: SELECT d.account_no, COALESCE(d.deposits, 0) - COALESCE(w.withdrawals, 0) 
   AS balance
  FROM (SELECT account_no, SUM(deposit_amount) AS deposits
   FROM deposits
  GROUP BY account_no) d
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT account_no, SUM(withdraw_amount) AS withdrawals
       FROM withdraws
       GROUP BY account_no) w ON w.account_no = d.account_no

Comment: Yes...but doesn't that still leave us with one subquery?